# Simply distributed index: precached 0 indexes

Tags: sphinx

I have two simple indexes:

First, `01.conf`:

```
searchd
{
    listen      = 9301
    listen      = 9401:mysql41
    pid_file    = /var/run/sphinxsearch/searchd01.pid
    log         = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd01.log
    query_log   = /var/log/sphinxsearch/query01.log
    binlog_path = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/test/01
}

source base
{
    type     = mysql
    sql_host = localhost
    sql_db   = test
    sql_user = root
    sql_pass = toor
    sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
    sql_attr_uint = group_id
}

source test : base
{
    sql_query               = \
                SELECT id, group_id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_added) AS date_added, title, content \
                FROM documents WHERE id % 2 = 0
}

index test
{
    source = test
    path   = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/test/01
}
```

Second looks like first but with "02" instead "01" in filename and inside.

And distributed index in `00.conf`:

```
searchd
{
    listen      = 9305
    listen      = 9405:mysql41
    pid_file    = /var/run/sphinxsearch/searchd00.pid
    log         = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd00.log
    query_log   = /var/log/sphinxsearch/query00.log
    binlog_path = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/test
}

index test
{
    type  = distributed
    agent = 127.0.0.1:9301:test
    agent = 127.0.0.1:9302:test
}
```

And I try to use distributed index:

```
sudo searchd --config /etc/sphinxsearch/d/00.conf --stop
sudo searchd --config /etc/sphinxsearch/d/01.conf --stop
sudo searchd --config /etc/sphinxsearch/d/02.conf --stop

sudo searchd --config /etc/sphinxsearch/d/01.conf
sudo searchd --config /etc/sphinxsearch/d/02.conf

sudo indexer --all --rotate --config /etc/sphinxsearch/d/01.conf
sudo indexer --all --rotate --config /etc/sphinxsearch/d/02.conf

sudo searchd --config /etc/sphinxsearch/d/00.conf
```

Unfortunately I obtain next output:

```
...
using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/d/00.conf'...
listening on all interfaces, port=9305
listening on all interfaces, port=9405
precached 0 indexes in 0.000 sec
```

Why?

And when I try to search something with distributed index (9305):

> no enabled local indexes to search.

And mysql indexes are works perfectly if I use them with port 9301 and 9302 respectively. But searching in distributed index returns nothing.

**UPDATE**

```
# tail  /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd00.log
[Thu Sep 29 23:43:04.599 2016] [ 2353] binlog: finished replaying /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/test/binlog.001; 0.0 MB in 0.000 sec
[Thu Sep 29 23:43:04.599 2016] [ 2353] binlog: finished replaying total 4 in 0.000 sec
[Thu Sep 29 23:43:04.599 2016] [ 2353] accepting connections
[Thu Sep 29 23:43:24.336 2016] [ 2353] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Sep 29 23:43:24.472 2016] [ 2353] shutdown complete
[Thu Sep 29 23:43:24.473 2016] [ 2352] watchdog: main process 2353 exited cleanly (exit code 0), shutting down
[Thu Sep 29 23:43:24.634 2016] [ 2404] watchdog: main process 2405 forked ok
[Thu Sep 29 23:43:24.635 2016] [ 2405] listening on all interfaces, port=9305
[Thu Sep 29 23:43:24.635 2016] [ 2405] listening on all interfaces, port=9405
[Thu Sep 29 23:43:24.636 2016] [ 2405] accepting connections
```

**UPDATE2**

Hmm... It seems what problem in querying data from Sphinx. Also I renamed distributed index into test1. Next code works well.

```
# mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 9405
mysql> select * from test1 where match ('one|two');
+------+----------+
| id   | group_id |
+------+----------+
|    1 |        1 |
|    2 |        1 |
+------+----------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

I think what problem was in old version of `sphinxapi.php` what I used.

Comment: How exactly do you make the search? API? Do you specify the index name (test) or just do the default ('*') one?

Comment: @aditirex Thanks, your question helped me!

Answer (score 1):

> precached 0 indexes in 0.000 sec

Well that it self, is normal. There are no local indexes to 'precache'. A distributed index has no index files to 'load' or (pre)cache.

... but searchd should still be running at the end of that. I think searchd should start up ok.

Try also checking 
/var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd00.log
might have some more.

Although I suppose its possible sphinx will not startup without any real indexes (ie cant have JUST distributed index), so could just add a fake index to that config.

Comment: Thank you for idea. I had tryed that. And found what problem was with how I querying data.